# How to get an element value in Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to get the value of `DomainName` from the below dictionary.

```
print(domain_name)

# output
{
    'DomainNames': [
        {
            'DomainName': 'some-value'
        },
    ]
}
```

I have tried:

```
print(domain_name['DomainNames'][0]['DomainName'])
```

but it doesn't give that value. I even tried:

```
print(domain_name['DomainNames']['DomainName'])
```

Here is my code:

```
def add_es_tags():

    for region in get_regions_depending_on_account():
        pass
    es_client = boto3.client('es', region_name="us-east-1")
    response = es_client.list_domain_names()

    get_es_domain_ARN("us-east-1", response)


def get_es_domain_ARN(region, domain_names):
    es_client = boto3.client('es', region_name=region)

    arns = [] 
    print(len(domain_names))
    for domain_name in domain_names:
        # print(type(domain_name))
        print(domain_name['DomainNames'][0]['DomainName'])
```

Comment: What *does* it give? If that was actually a dictionary holding a list of dictionaries, I'd expect the first attempt to work, `domain_name['DomainNames'][0]['DomainName']` gives the expected `'some-value'` locally.

Comment: first attempt gives this error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: So it seems you don't have a dictionary, you have a *string*. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/988228/3001761

Comment: To determine the type of an object you can use `print(type(domain_name))`.

Comment: Post your code so we can reproduce your issue

Comment: it gives this ourput @Axe319: `<class 'str'> <class 'str'>`

Comment: I updated the question @nicomp

Comment: Post fully executable, broken code.

Comment: @ToRrent you have a json string, you need to unserialize it to Python. boto3.client might already provide this feature in it's API, else you can do it by yourself using `json.loads()` (from the stdlib's json module).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
domain_name = {
    'DomainNames': [
        {
            'DomainName': 'some-value'
        },
    ]
}

print(domain_name)

print(domain_name['DomainNames'][0]['DomainName'])
```

Yes, the answer is: it works exactly as you suggested!

Edit: Never mind, I'll update this when you've formulated a full question that actually matches what you're doing.